# Webservlet urlpatterns for index.jsp

Tags: css, servlets, indexing, url-pattern

I'm stuck with this problem and I can't find a solution for it anywhere, so any ideas are welcome.

I want to execute some code on a `@WebServlet (javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet)` before it loads my index.jsp. For that I added "/" to the urlPatterns. This does what it's expected in the index.jsp, but it doesn't load my css or image paths any more. The problem is the "/" makes it include all other files in these urlPatterns, but if I try to use "index" instead, it doesn't work.

Can someone please help?

Cheers,
M.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `url-pattern` which **exactly** matches `/index.jsp`.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/index.jsp" })
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete question, I wonder if you can't better use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) (which is annotable using [`@WebListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html)). This is certainly true when your sole functional requirement is to preload/preinitialize some application-wide data on server's startup, regardless of the first-opened webpage.